# WPF: поиск по TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день!

Интересует поиск элемента TreeViewItem в TreeView.

Знаю, что [на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff407130(v=vs.110).aspx) лежало решение, но на данный момент блоки с кодом пусты и я не знаю, как быть :(

В WinForms, например, можно было

```
if(treeView.Nodes[0].Text == "smth")
{ 
   //do smth
}
```

А как быть с WPF?

---

По совету ниже начала постигать азы MVVM, и мозг благополучно скопытился.
Раньше у меня данные из коллекции попадали в TreeView, а теперь нужно сделать промежуточное Tree во ViewModel, к которому биндится TreeView, или как?

---

Если я правильно понимаю, для корректной работы нужно использовать байндинги.
Затык на том, что во vm есть диспетчер (его я сделала DataContext'ом окна), у которого есть два словаря-категории (dictionary), а у одного из словарей почти у каждого из элементов есть свой словарь, и нужно вывести в таком формате:

-категория 1
--элемент словаря
--элемент словаря
---все элементы словаря элемента словаря
--элемент словаря
-категория 2
--элемент словаря

из-за того, что вложенность большая, я в HierarchicalDataTemplate'ах ковыряюсь, но без толку.

Comment: С WPF принято использовать MVVM, поэтому поиск сводится к поиску среди графа вьюмоделей где сами данные лежат, а не работе с контролом.

Comment: В [предыдущей версии](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff407130(v=vs.100).aspx) непусты. Но и правда искать лучше в VM, а не в контролах.

Comment: @vitidev
Отредактировала вопрос, можете подсказать?:)

Comment: Я слабо понимаю вашу проблему, но есть поговорка "Любую проблему можно решить путём введения дополнительного уровня абстракции, кроме проблемы слишком большого количества уровней абстракции". Если вы не можете забиндить исходную структуру на шаблон, то вам надо сделать обертку в виде вьюмодели которая выдаст нужные данные для биндинга. И вообще возьмите за правило создавать обертки вьюмоделей для моделей. Это оно поначалу кажется лишней работой,  но на деле нужно практически всегда что не ReadOnly

Comment: @vitidev спасибо за подсказку, я попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим способы работы.

**Прямое заполнение дерева**

Проходя по нашим данным программно заполняем дерево, создаем ноды и заполняем их данными.

Найти нужную ноду с данными можно так:

- Бегаем по дереву-контролу как вот вы в WinForms бегали, расковыриваем контролы и смотрим данные. Очень неудобно, ведь шаблон ноды может быть любой. Поменяем что-то и поиск придется чинить.
- Ищем в исходных данных по которым строили дерево. Находим. Но как узнать ноду? Значит кроме данных нужно хранить соответствие "пункт данных<->узел в дереве". То есть создаем карту сопоставления данных визуальному узлу дерева.

Получаем ссылку на контрол узла дерева и дальше можем с ним что-то делать.

**MVVM вариант**

В MVVM не принято ковырять контролы руками без нужды, а делать вьюмодели и доверить WPF используя механизм шаблонов и биндингов отображать визуально эти вьюмодели

поэтому для мы строим логическое дерево из данных, а WPF по заданным шаблонам создаст его визуальную проекцию.

Более того, после нахождения узла данных (вьюмодель) не следует пытаться узнавать какой контрол в визуальном дереве отображает этот узел. Вьюмодель **не имеет** ссылки на WPF. Нужно менять что-то внутри этой найденной вьюмодели, а WPF будет следить за этим и отображать изменения в визуальной части.

Comment: А можно немного конкретики? Как построить логическое дерево из данных, лежащих в коллекции?

Comment: @JaneDoe ну если руками, то так http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level22/22_6.php

Comment: Руками не совсем правильно, разве нет? В комментариях ограниченные возможности, поэтому добавила текст к вопросу.

Comment: @JaneDoe нет такого понятия "правильно". Каждый строит дерево как ему удобно. Я вот использую MVVM везде, но если мне надо руками что-то подправить, то не чураюсь кода в code-behind и свои контролы и аттачеды и прочее, где чистый код. Ваш изначальный вопрос не про MVVM (в котором построить несложно - примеров в сети масса),  и даже не про построение дерева, а про поиск в дереве.

Comment: поняла вас. Просто логично сначала построить, а потом уже искать :) Потому и начала спрашивать. Спасибо.

Comment: @JaneDoe Вообще то моя мысль была в том, что логичнее искать в данных, нежели  бегать по визуальным контролам (которые могут меняться со временем). А значит вместо "как искать по контролу" нужно думать "как организовать данные для поиска (если надо) и как сопоставить их с визуальными узлами (если надо)". В ручном режиме это будет карта сопоставлений данные-визуальный узел. В MVVM каждый узел будет иметь ссылку на вьюмодель/модель узла как DataContext, то есть сам будет следить за данными.

Comment: Я поняла вас, правда. Любопытный механизм. Получается, что вместо связывания напрямую View <=> Model, нужен посредник, которого не придется впоследствии менять. А над посредником уже изгаляться)

Comment: @JaneDoe Похоже я еще больше вас запутал. Изменябельный посредник тут не причем. Просто работать нужно с данными, искать в них, фильтровать. А дальше либо руками что-то в гуи менять при смене данных (например фильтрация), либо доверить это механизмам биндингов WPF и вообще не притрагиваться к контролам UI в коде. А вьюмодели (считай обертки  над моделями) в MVVM полезны тем, что у них появляется IsSelected/IsVisible/IsEnabled, которые логически не должны принадлежать моделям, потому и оборачивают в класс вьюмодели, чтобы хранить там.